# unable to resolve a function using string Polation in JavaScript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am  counting number of items a user has checked on the checkbox but unable to resolve a function using string Polation in JavaScript/Angular. I can get the output on the console but not sure how to get it on the screen. 
Can anyone please assist me with this small query. please let me know  if there's any efficient/better way to do it. Kinda new of Angular/JS

```
<span  style="white-space: nowrap; padding-right:130px;"> {{ this['groupType'] | pluralize}} Selected</span>
```

Below is the piece of code from my TS file. Here is where I am getting the count from.

```
 numberOfStudentsSelected($event){
    if($event){
      if($event.checked === true){
        this.count ++
      }
      else if($event.checked === false){
        this.count --;
      }
      console.log(this.count);
    }
```

That's what I have currently on the screen.
[image]

Comment: You're not returning anything it seems.

Comment: You are printing `this.count` to the console but haven't used it in anywhere your template. Use `{{ count }}` in the HTML template to display the value of `count`

Comment: `this` should also not display in HTML... use `{{groupType}}` or  `{{count}}`. Make sure they are `public groupType; public count;` in Typescript when accessing from HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 numberOfStudentsSelected($event){
    if($event){
      if($event.checked === true){
        return this.count ++
      }
      else if($event.checked === false){
        return this.count --;
      }
      console.log(this.count);
    }
```

Comment: When returning values like this it should be `return ++this.count` instead

Comment: @cyberpirate92 I have another question/issue that I encountered..This number/count appears on a dialog modal. If I close the modal and open it. The count resets to `0` . I can use localstorage but don't want to incline towards that if there is a better way you can suggest. I am using Angular. let me know if you want me to share any piece of code you might want to have a look at .

Comment: @Dwayne I'll have to take a look at the code first, please ask a new question and include a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) if possible